# Что значит индексация в контексте Git?

Tags: git, терминология

Начал разбираться в системе контроле версий Git и понял что не могу понять, что означает термин индексация. Приведу пример :

> Изменения файла hello.html были проиндексированы. Это означает, что git теперь знает об изменении, но изменение пока не перманентно (читай, навсегда) записано в репозиторий. Следующий коммит будет включать в себя проиндексированные изменения.Если вы решили, что не хотите коммитить изменения, команда состояния напомнит вам о том, что с помощью команды git reset можно снять индексацию этих изменений.

Так вот вопрос, как здесь понимать индексацию?

Comment: Читай мануал. Индекс - это состояние **подготовленное** для коммита. Есть такие категории файлов в гите как: **untracked**, **modified**, **staged (index)** и **committed**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### что такое индексирование?

индексирование (также: indexing, staging) — это процесс добавления текущего содержимого (изменённого) файла в индекс (также: index area, staging area).

---

#### какой командой выполняется это добавление?

командой `add`:

```
$ git add файл
```

---

#### что при этом происходит с технической точки зрения?

берётся содержимое файла, впереди к нему дописывается немного служебной информации, высчитывается sha1sum от получившегося (это т.н. хэш), затем всё это сжимается и сохраняется в файле в каталоге `.git/objects`. имя файла уникально, т.к. формируется на основании полученного хэша.
затем в [файл `.git/index`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt) дописывается ещё одна запись о добавленном файле (сохраняется имя файла, а также тот самый хэш, и ещё некоторое количество служебной информации):

```
| файл         | хэш | ... |
| каталог/файл | хэш | ... |
```

---

#### и что, этот файл `.git/index` всё растёт и растёт? он же станет со временем гигантского размера!

записи в этом файле заново пересоздаются в результате переключения содержимого рабочего каталога командой `checkout`. кстати, именно из этого файла программа *git* черпает информацию о том, какие именно изменения должны быть зафиксированы с помощью commit-а (используется содержимое этого файла и при некоторых других операциях — см. [подробнее в документации](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/racy-git.txt)). среди других команд, добавляющих либо удаляющих записи в этом файле, стоит отметить `reset`, `rm`, `stash`.

---

#### так для чего он вообще нужен, этот «индекс»?

с технической точки зрения основная цель его существования — избежать (ресурсоёмких) операций с файлами в рабочем каталоге (working tree) при выполнении команды `commit`. благодаря его наличию при выполнении команды `commit` не производится никаких манипуляций с файлами в рабочем каталоге — ни поиск изменённых файлов, ни сжатие их текущего содержимого. (оговорка: при наличии опций `-a/--all/-p/--patch/--interactive` команды `commit` все эти оптимизации «идут коту под хвост»: выполняется и поиск и сжатие).

Comment: А разве файл индекса очищается при выполнении `commit`? Вроде он так и остается кэшем, и используется для построения следующего коммита

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, спасибо за замечание. действительно, неправильно написал. исправил.

Comment: *"основная цель его существования — избежать (ресурсоёмких) операций с файлами в рабочем каталоге (working tree) при выполнении команды commit"* - ¿Каким же образом оно позволяет избежать упомянутых ресурсоемких операций, если они всё равно выполняются при наполнении индекса?

Answer (score 1):

Индекс - это временный коммит, которого еще нет в истории.

При выполнении команды `git commit` именно индекс, а не текущее состояние рабочей копии становится новым коммитом. Сразу после выполнения `commit` или `checkout` индекс совпадает с последним коммитом текущей ветки.

`git add` помещает текущее состояние файла в индекс. Это и есть индексация.

`git status` нам показывает два списка файлов:

1. `Changes to be committed:` (выводятся зеленым) — это разница между последним коммитом и индексом, то, что попадет в коммит.
2. `Changes not staged for commit:` (выводятся красным) — это разница между индексом и рабочей копией, то, что в коммит не попадет.

Answer (score 0):

Это означает, что git теперь знает **какие именно** изменения были сделаны в файле.

Comment: тоесть, индексация это процесс изменения файлов?

Comment: @hormanfurman Индексация это процесс добавления сделанных изменений в гит. Гит не будет знать об изменениях, пока они не будут специально добавлены командой git add

Comment: Нет, процесс изменения файлов в данном случае это собственно программирование. А индексация - добавление информации об изменениях в базу гита, скажем так.

Comment: боже, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

В английской версии оно выглядит так:

> Changes to the hello.html have been **staged**.

Тут речь про staging. Изменения выбраны, но в коммит ещё не добавлены)
Другими словами, выполнен `git add`, но `git commit` пока нет.

**staging** — это просто **промежуточный** этап, который позволяет выбрать, какие именно изменения будут добавлены в следующий коммит.

**Индекс** стейджинг этапа - это некий слепок содержимого рабочей директории, который и будет использован при коммите. Если файлы были изменены после git add, при коммите будет зафиксировано их состояние в **индексе**.

В `git status` эти изменения отображаются отдельно, зелёным цветом)

Answer (score 0):

Индекс в Git — это черновик коммита.

Индексирование/индексацию — добавление в индекс.

Answer (score 0):

А можно, чтобы было проще для моего неокрепшего мозга, представить себе индекс как буфер, в котором предварительно сохраняются все изменения перед фиксацией/commit`ом? Не факт, что все изменения будут закоммичены/зафиксированы. Возможно, часть из них будет отменена, другая часть сгруппирована и пойдет одним коммитом, третьи пойдут отдельными коммитами.
Это не попытка, что-то оспорить или опровергнуть. Это моё сложившееся видение индекса простым, для меня, языком. Написал, чтобы более знающие люди поправили меня, если я не прав или, наоборот, подтвердили мое понимание.
Ну, и, возможно, новичкам будет проще въехать в тему.
Заранее благодарю за конструктивную критику.